# How to add image after button/div css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add something like the following in my project; how can I do it using After?

[image: Div:After]

Comment: Where is your code? and your question not clear!

Comment: I just want to know the base and how to do it, img is here 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/fVqrR.png

Comment: You should put some code, what you have done so far. anyway, I don't understand, I didn't see any image beside your buttons in that picture. please explain more in your question.

Comment: You can check this link for instance.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889909/div-after-add-content-after-div

Comment: http://codepen.io/d3vma/pen/ONjzpP

Comment: Well i saw your pen, you want add hr line between your buttons?

Comment: this want i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted? Try adding this after your css:

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(1)>button> .circle-item h2:after,
.col-md-4:nth-child(2)>button> .circle-item h2:after{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  content: "_____________";
  color: black;
}
```